# Rails4 // Protect visibility of parameters

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

Is it possible, like it is for the "password" parameter in devise for example, to declare other parameters that would need to be hidden from logs ? If possible, how should it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add any parameters you want to filter to the file `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

password is already filtered so just add any others to the array `[:password,:hidden_parameter]`